# Path finding - Merging different cost functions

Tags: path-finding

In my path finding school project, the user is given 3 options to navigate between two points:

1. Shortest path (Kilometers). I've defined the cost function for each 2 points to be the distance of the road that connects them.
2. Fastest path (Each road has a speed limit). I've defined the cost function between each 2 points to be 1/(SpeedLimit).
3. Simplest path (Minimizes turns, a turn is defined if the road changes direction by more than alpha degrees). I've defined a state to be a tuple of a point and direction, and defined the cost function to be 1 if the change of direction is larger than alpha and 0 otherwise.

The user then supplies 3 real numbers between 0 and 1 to specify the importance of each navigating option.

So basically the cost function should be the sum of the three cost functions described above, each multiplied by the number supplied. My problem is that each cost function is of different units, for example, the first cost function is in kilometers and the third cost function is boolean (0 or 1).
How can I convert them so that it makes sense?

Comment: You can consider the third cost function being the number of turns. This way is no longer a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Define a cost function for each criteria that maps from a path to a real number.

- f1(path) = cost associated with the distance of the path
- f2(path) = cost of the time taken to traverse the path
- f3(path) = cost of the complexity of the route

Defining `f1` and `f2` should be fairly straightforward. `f3` is more complex and subjective but I suspect it really shouldn't be a boolean unless there's some very specific reason why you would need it to be. Perhaps the function for path complexity could be something like the sum of the number of degrees (radians) in every turn taken in the trip. There's certainly quite a few other choices for such a function that immediately come to mind, (for example the length of the representation required to describe the path). For `f3` you will have to choose whatever one suits your purposes best.

Once you have defined the individual cost functions you could get an overall cost for the path by taking a linear combination of those 3 functions:

cost(path) = a1*f1(path) + a2*f2(path) + a3*f3(path)

Finding sensible values for `a1, a2, a3` is most of the challenge. There are a few statistical methods you might want to use to do this.